# How to show search result in angular 4

Tags: angular, filter, angular-components

I have a filter component where 2 fields are available to filter directory list and a search button.

I want to show filtered result in main component where all the directory listing is showing.

Actually all is working fine, when i click on search button, search function run in filter.component.ts file and get the results from api and show the result in console. but i unable to pass the result to main component where filtered listing have to be shown.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code samples. I hope you are simply filtering the already fetch data. If it absolutely requires you to fetch another set of data, you need to send that data back to the parent component.

There are many ways to do this. Either using @Output to emit a function to the parent component. Or use a service and an Observable.

Here is a sample you asked for when using services. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

```
// test.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/subject';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  // Source
  private list = new Subject<Object[]>();

  // Observable Stream
  public list$ = this.list.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  updateList(data) {
    this.list.next(data);
  }
}

// parent.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from 'services/test.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-name',
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
  providers: []
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  list;

  constructor(
    private testService: TestService
  ) {
    testService.list$.subscribe(data => {
      this.list = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
}

// child.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from 'services/test.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-name',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html'
})

export class ChilComponent implements OnInit {
  list;

  constructor(
    private testService: TestService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  update(){
    this.testService.updateList(list);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used @Output to emit a function in main component and it worked. Please share your example using service and Observable. I am new in angular so don't have much idea about that.